# How to install cryptography on ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, cryptography, pip

My ubuntu is 14.04 LTS.

When I install cryptography, the error is:

```
Installing egg-scripts.
uses namespace packages but the distribution does not require setuptools.
Getting distribution for 'cryptography==0.2.1'.

no previously-included directories found matching 'documentation/_build'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
six: module references __path__

Installed /tmp/easy_install-oUz7ei/cryptography-0.2.1/.eggs/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg
Searching for cffi>=0.8
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/
Best match: cffi 1.5.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-1.5.0.tar.gz#md5=dec8441e67880494ee881305059af656
Processing cffi-1.5.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-oUz7ei/cryptography-0.2.1/temp/easy_install-Yf2Yl3/cffi-1.5.0/setup.cfg
Running cffi-1.5.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-oUz7ei/cryptography-0.2.1/temp/easy_install-Yf2Yl3/cffi-1.5.0/egg-dist-tmp-A2kjMD
c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ffi.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
An error occurred when trying to install cryptography 0.2.1. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing egg-scripts.
  Getting distribution for 'cryptography==0.2.1'.
Error: Couldn't install: cryptography 0.2.1
```

I don't know why it was failed. What is the reason. Is there something necessary when install it on ubuntu system?

Comment: Please read the Linux part of the docs: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you. I didn't check the document carefully. After I installed the necessary ubuntu packages, I can install cryptography successful. But when I tried to install it on Mac OS X, there also has an error: `cffi.ffiplatform.VerificationError: CompileError: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1`. I think this time is special due to my system.

Comment: That should be a new question or a google query at first.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, I will post a new question. Thank you very much for this. If you like to write the answer here, I will accept it.

Comment: @ithelloworld please consider "accep"-ting an answer.

Answer (score 132):

The answer is on the docs of `cryptography`'s [installation section](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-linux) which pretty much reflects Angelos' answer:

Quoting it:

> For Debian and **Ubuntu**, the following command will ensure that the
>   required dependencies are installed:
>
> ```
> $ sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev
> ```
>
> For Fedora and RHEL-derivatives, the following command will ensure
>   that the required dependencies are installed:
>
> ```
> $ sudo yum install gcc libffi-devel python-devel openssl-devel
> ```
>
> You should now be able to build and install cryptography with the
>   usual
>
> ```
> $ pip install cryptography
> ```

If you're using Python 3, please use `python3-dev` instead of `python-dev` in the first command. (thanks to @chasmani)

If you're installing this on `Ubuntu 18.04`, please use `libssl1.0` instead of `libssl-dev` in the first command. (thanks to @pobe)

Comment: You will also need python3-dev if you are using python3. So sudo apt-get install python3-dev

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 : **apt install libssl1.0**, took me forever to find it.

Comment: @Pobe THANK YOU!!! It took me *forever* to find that :P I created a separate question to hopefully help future folks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57684081

Comment: @Pobe - thank you! I spent way too long trying to figure out that I needed to install libssl1.0.

Comment: @chasmani: I've included in your responses to make it easier to find. Thank you.

Comment: @pobe: I've included in your responses to make it easier to find. Thank you.

Answer (score 49):

I had the same problem when pip installing the cryptography module on Ubuntu 14.04. I solved it by installing libffi-dev:

```
apt-get install -y libffi-dev
```

Then I got the following error:

```
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_openssl.c:431:25: fatal error: openssl/aes.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/aes.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Which I resolved by installing libssl-dev:

```
apt-get install -y libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Installing libssl-dev and python-dev was enough for me on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?