# Pip disabled after trying to upgrade Openssl

Tags: python, openssl, pip, tweepy

I've been trying to use tweepy which requieres pyOpenssl, but after trying to upgrade Openssl I'm getting this error which actually disable my pip for any package

```
$ pip install cryptography
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2598, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2258, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2264, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 22, in <module>
    import requests, six
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
    _attach_namespace(urllib3, 'requests.packages')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 63, in _attach_namespace
    module = __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 55, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 112, in <module>
    if _lib.Cryptography_HAS_SSL_ST:
AttributeError: 'FFILibrary' object has no attribute 'Cryptography_HAS_SSL_ST'
```

Now, as I said, I can't install anything since this error keeps apearing. I already tried to follow the recomendation on the following link but without any success

[How to install cryptography on ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144550/how-to-install-cryptography-on-ubuntu)

The version of python is 2.7 and linux is debian

Thanks

Comment: Broken package management usually happens when you upgrade OpenSSL, but you use a version which is *not* binary compatible with the former version. You will probably need to restore the former version of OpenSSL. Do so by copying them from backup, or copying them from a different machine.